# Semicolons when creating a CSV file instead of colons

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-excel, csv

When creating a CSV file from an XLSX workbook with the new Excel for Windows 8, I get a file filled with semicolons instead of colons.

How can I change that? I even had to reopen the file with Wordpad to find out why my file could not be exported to a data management program.

Comment: What's the new excel? 2013?

Answer (score 8):

Your Windows regional settings are set to use semi-colons instead of commas as the list seperator symbol. You'll have to re-configure those in order to force Excel to use colons instead of semi-colons.

Check out this page to find out how to do that: http://www.rawcomputing.co.uk/windows8/windows-8-tip12.html The list seperator symbol should be configurable on the window that pops up when clicking the "Additional settings..." button on the "Region" window.

Comment: Note, that in newer Excel versions you can change the `list separator` right from within your Excel options

Comment: Oh? I'm using Excel 2013 and just scrolled through the options without finding any option. Where exactly can you configure the list separator symbol in my version?

Comment: Sorry, I may have confused [thousands separator with list separator](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/300167)

Comment: Okay, yes. I found that option as well. What I didn't find was an option for list seperators though.

Comment: This change will also affect Opening of CSV files in Excel and possibly more windows programs.
If you want to make more compatible CSV file, put `sep=,` on top of the CSV file, then once you save the file, you can change List Separator back to whatever it was.

Comment: Cool. I did not know that trick. You might want to add it as an own answer.

Comment: Why does it use CSV file extension? CSV stands for COMMA separated list. If they use SEMICOLON separated list, they should use SSV, isn't they?

Comment: @Dims: Though this could be a question on its own, and this is not really the right place for an answer, I'll add my assumption here nevertheless: In some regions (like Germany) the decimal separator is a comma instead of a dot. That's why formulas will have to be written `=SUM(0,8; 1,2)` there instead of `=JUST(0.8, 1.2)`. As Excel will export decimal values using the Windows regional settings, it coherently will also use its list separator. (Obviously the two separators should be different from each other - or else the line `1,2,3,4` in a CSV file could mean both `1.2`, `3.4` and `1,2,3,4`.)